# Problems with preg_match function

Tags: php, preg-match

I've just made a few edits to a file and when testing it seemed to not work, I did a bit of debugging and found that preg_match was returning 0, I've looked into it and cannot see what the problem is, also since I haven't touched this part of the file, I'm confused as to what might have happened...

```
<?php
echo preg_match('/[A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+/', 'testeR123');
?>
```

This is a snippet I'm using for debugging, I'm guessing my pattern is wrong, but I am probably wrong about that.

Thanks,
P110

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/zH4tA5

Comment: What do you expect from this preg_match? What is the pattern you want to match?

Comment: That should match Tester123 since your regex is looking for a capital letter first

Comment: I'm just looking for it to check if there is an uppercase, lowercase and a number, but from the replies, my pattern checks for it in an order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment:

> I'm just looking for it to check if there is an uppercase, lowercase and a number, but from the replies, my pattern checks for it in an order

have a try with:

```
preg_match('/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', $input_string);
```

where

`(?=.*[A-Z])` checks there are at least one uppercase
`(?=.*[a-z])` checks there are at least one lowercase
`(?=.*[0-9])` checks there are at least one digit
`[A-Za-z0-9]+` checks there are only these characters.

`(?=...)` is called [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: I'll try this soon, if it does what I'm looking for ill mark this as answer

Answer (score 0):

Your regex first test if there are Capital letters from A to Z then if there are lowercase letters from at to z and then if there are numbers. since your string starts with an lowercase it will not match.

i think you want to do this

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Or if you need that your string starts with a lowecase string then an uppercase string and then numbers you should change the regex to.

```
[a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+
```

In that way your current string would fit the regex as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order of the letters:
Try this:

`echo preg_match('/[a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+/', 'testeR123');`

Or:

`echo preg_match('/[A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+/', 'Rtest123');`

Or simpler

`echo preg_match('/[A-Z]+[0-9]+/i', 'testeR123');`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
preg_match('/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/', 'testeR123', $match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but when I tried to implement it went funny but I've found an answer so thanks anyway